# Create BigQuery materialized view using Cloud Deployment Manager

Tags: google-bigquery, google-deployment-manager

I can create native and external tables, as well as views in BigQuery using Deployment Manager, however, there doesn't seem to be any way to create a materialized view. Page at:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro says its still in beta - is it typical for GCP beta features to have no support in Deployment Manager?

Is there a workaround for this? Only thing I can think of is using a Job resource https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert and specifying a DDL query like: `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...` but I don't think Deployment Manager will track and manage the resource correctly.

Edit: for anyone else, this works even though not documented:

```
- name: test-mv
  type: bigquery.v2.table
  properties:
    datasetId: experiments
    tableReference:
      datasetId: experiments
      tableId: test_mv
    materializedView:
      query: "select test, COUNT(*) as counter from experiments.test group by test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *Google Cloud Deployment Manager* [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types#apis_for_supported_resources) `bigquery.v2.table` resource type is actually leveraging [tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables) REST object as a part of [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) inventory.

Having said this, I assume that you can fully rely on [tables.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) method as per Bigquery guidelines [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#api):

> Call the **tables.insert** method with a defined `materializedView` resource
>   as part of your API request. The `materializedView` resource contains a
>   query field.

```
"materializedView": {
    "query": "select product_id,sum(clicks) as
                sum_clicks from project-id.my_dataset.my_base_table
                group by 1"
  }
```

Defining appropriate `materializedView` property in the initial deployment [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-basic-configuration) or Python/Jinja [template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template).

I haven't tested yet the mentioned above API functionality, but once you have any further doubts with the implementation I'll try to dig deeper.